# How can I unit test uwp app with NUnit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp, nunit

I have no idea on NUnit Test Framework , I have searched for uwp app with nunit test but cant find any example, this is a related article: [How to run UWP NUnit tests in with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246626/how-to-run-uwp-nunit-tests-in-with-visual-studio-2015) , but this doesnt make sense to me , what do i need on unit testing uwp app with nunit test framework, packages needed to be install?

Let's Just say I want to unit test a simple method Like Add and Sub:

```
public int Add(int num1, int num2){
 return num1 + num2;
}

public int Sub(int num1, int num2){
 return num1 - num2;
}
```

**UPDATE: What I did so far is create a unit test app(universal window)
then on project.json or reference remove MSTest and replace it with *NUnit* and *NUnit3TestAdapter* and here is my UnitTest.cs :**

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(4, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems to be not reading my Test as a test, what am I missing?

Comment: Please add more detail to this question. What's a piece of code you're trying to unit test? What have you tried and what errors did you see?

Comment: @TracyMoody Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Everything coming from MS is broken these days. Here's one guys struggle to get things working, but it's from a couple of years ago.  A bit has changed since then, but currently, only MSTests will work without ripping out your hair.

http://krzyskowk.postach.io/post/unit-tests-in-uwp